# How do we store relationships in usergrid?

Tags: cassandra, apigee, usergrid, nosql

I have two collections 1)Cities 2) CarShowrooms. Now when I search for a car showroom let's say "Suzuki", I want to list all possible cities that has Suzuki show room.

On the other hand I want to list all CarShowrooms in a city.

Since it is a no-sql db, the only way to do this is to store cinema info at the CarShowroom and CarShowroom info on cinema. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usergrid has a very flexible relationship structure that you can use as [documented here](https://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/docs/relationships/).

In your example, you could create a one-way relationship (using entity names, but you could use UUIDs instead) like this:

> curl -X POST https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/Cities/Miami/showrooms/CarShowrooms/Suzuki

Then, to retrieve the showrooms in Miami, you could perform:

> curl https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/Cities/Miami/showrooms

Scott

See also the [Apigee documentation](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/connecting-users-other-data).